# IONIC 4 ERROR ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I'm getting error while building ionic4 app to android release.[Here is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoM75.png)

Ionic:

```
Ionic CLI : 5.2.3 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic) Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.6.2 @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9 @angular-devkit/schematics : 7.3.9 @angular/cli : 7.3.9 @ionic/angular-toolkit : 1.5.1
```

Cordova:

```
Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, browser 6.0.0 Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 13 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
cordova-res : 0.6.0 native-run : 0.2.8
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe) npm : 6.10.2 OS : Windows 10
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the error, don't post a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Show me your `config.xml`. Do you have the following code on the widget?

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

If not, add it and build again.